# How to debug/execute a Ocaml program step by step?

Tags: debugging, emacs, ocaml

I am wondering if it is possible to debug/execute a Ocaml program step by step, for instance like debugging C++ programs in Visual Studio. In other words, I would like to run a Ocaml program line by line, also it would be great if we could "watch" the value of some variables.

By the way, I am using Emacs as editor.

Could anyone help? Thank you very much

Edit-1: As sepp2k suggested, I am trying to run camldebug under Emacs. I have a problem in the beginning: the web page mentions "The Caml debugger is started under Emacs by the command `M-x camldebug`, with argument the name of the executable file `progname` to debug." Actually I have only 3 choices:

```
M-x camldebug
M-x camldebug-mode
M-x camldebug-step
```

Edit-2: When I type `M-x camldebug`, enter, it shows `Symbol's value as variable is void: caml-mode-map` which does not allow me to enter the executable file.

Could anyone help? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can step through the code using the debugger [ocamldebug](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/debugger.html), which can be [run in emacs](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/debugger.html#sec403).

Comment: @SoftTimur: Enter camldebug, press enter, then enter the name of the program.

Comment: @SoftTimur That error is a [bug in recent versions of Tuareg mode](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=614933). A suggested workaround is to run `M-x caml-mode` or `M-x load-library caml-mode` first; another workaround is to run the official Emacs `camldebug` support instead of the Tuareg support (`(autoload 'camldebug "camldebug" "Run the Caml debugger" t)` in your `.emacs` should do the trick).

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for your comment... After installing the package `ocaml-mode`, and running `M-x caml-mode`, I could run `M-x camldebug`...

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is telling you to supply the executable file's name to `camldebug`. You can do this by `M-x camldebug`, then press enter, and then type in the path of the executable when emacs prompts you for it.